# How to send interrupt to Celery worker from Flask?

Tags: python, flask, signals, celery, interrupt

**Question**

I've read up some on accessing status from a Celery worker from a Flask application, like in this [tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask), but can you go the other way? Send an interrupt or get introspection into a Celery worker after it's been started?

I've read a bit about [signals](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html), but either don't understand them yet or it's not what I'm looking for. Possibly both.

**Background**

I'm using Celery to kick off a long-running loop that subscribes to an MQTT topic, I'd like to be able to also shut down that process/subscription from another endpoint in my Flask app. What's the best way to do this? Or a way?

**Example Code**

```
from flask import Flask
from celery import Celery
import time

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)

@celery.task(bind=True)
def test_loop(self):
    i=0
    running = True
    while running:
        i = i+1
        print "loop running %d" % i
        time.sleep(1)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'index page'

@app.route('/start')
def start():
    global task
    task = test_loop.delay()
    return "started loop"

@app.route('/stop')
def stop():
    global task             ### What I'm having trouble with
    task.running = False    ### How can I interrupt/introspect into the task?
    return "stopped loop"
```

**TL/DR**

Is there a way to send an interrupt or get introspection into a Celery worker after it's been started? How can I stop a long-running loop started in a Celery Worker from Flask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal thoughts behind this would be to stay away from tasks that run forever.

If you absolutely must abort a task then you can use revoke.
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#revoke-revoking-tasks

```
@app.route('/stop')
def stop():
    global task
    task.revoke(terminate=True, signal='SIGKILL')
    return "stopped loop"
```

Celery may be overkill for your use case but I'm not totally sure what your end goal is so I can't really offer any alternatives.

Comment: Awesome, that could work. I also thought that Celery was overkill at first, but couldn't get multiprocessing to work.

My end goal is to collect, log, plot, and analyze temperature readings from a wireless BBQ thermometer while smoking BBQ, usually a session ranging from a few to over 12 hours. I'm receiving the readings from [rtl433](https://github.com/merbanan/rtl_433), which can output received data as MQTT messages. Right now I've got that running essentially all the time on a Raspberry Pi, so it can separate the dependencies on RTLSDR hardware from the web server.

Comment: On the web server I subscribe to the MQTT topic and write new messages to a JSON file. That is the long running task mocked up by `test_loop` in my code above. 

I'd like to be able to pass some configuration from Flask, like the log path and filename, as well as control when it starts/stops writing. Since the MQTT client (I'm using [paho-mqtt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paho-mqtt/1.1) sets up connections and hangs out with a `while True: time.sleep(1)` waiting on messages, I'm not sure an alternative to a long-running task.

Can you think of a better way?